# React native project

Tags: node.js, npm, react.js

I have a problem with creating a new react native project, When I run

```
react-native init AwesomeApp
```

all I get is only (package.json and yarn-error.log) there is no iOS or Android folders in the command

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/man/AwesomeApp
Using yarn v1.16.0
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.16.0
error An unexpected error occurred: "/Users/man/package.json: Unexpected end of JSON input".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/man/AwesomeApp/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 70691,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed.
```

My stack is:

- node: v12.5.0
- npm: 6.10.0
- yarn: 1.16.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: n/a – not inside a React Native project directory

Answer (score 2):

You have a `package.json` in your home folder. This `package.json` appears to be invalid.

I suggest you remove it, it most likely should not be there anyway.

Yarn is for whatever reason also looking at parent `package.json` files.

(Additionally, it is suggested you not install `react-native` but use `npx` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install

This command are installed you iOS and Android file or node module